Evans PDE: details of the proof in the Meyers-Serrin theorem
There is a question about the following proof of this theorem:
${\bf Global\ Approximation\ Theorem}$(251 page inEvans's PDE book) : Assume $U$ is bounded, then for $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$,
there exists $u_m \in C^\infty (U)\cap W^{k,p}(U)$ such that
$$u_m \rightarrow u\ in\ W^{k,p}(U)$$
https://i.sstatic.net/IdlxA.jpg
My questions is: Why I could't attain the inequality on U directly? Like
$$\left \| v-u \right \| _{W^{k,p}(U)} \le \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left \| u^i-\zeta_i u \right \|_ {W^{k,p}(U)} $$
Thanks in advance!

One does not know that the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \zeta_iu$ converges to $u$ on the full domain $U$. On $V$ that is compactly contained in $U$ this is clear: on such a set, the series reduces to a finite sum.

@daw But we define $\left {  \zeta_i\right } {i=0}^\infty$ by $\sum{i=0}^\infty \zeta_i=1 $ on $ \textit{U}$.  So I think $ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \zeta_i u=u $?

This is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^n \zeta_i u \to u$ for $n \to\infty$. The problem is to prove this convergence  in $W^{1,p}(U)$.

@daw Got your point. Thank you very much!

@daw I think I have another idea to prove $\left | \sum_{i=0}^\infty u^i - \zeta_i u \right | \le  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left | u^i - \zeta_i u \right | $. First, because we know that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left | u^i - \zeta_i u \right | < \infty$, $\left { \sum_{i=0}^n u^i - \zeta_i u \right }n $ is a Cauchy sequence in $W^{k,p}(U)$ by triangle inequality. Thus, $\left { \sum{i=0}^n u^i - \zeta_i u \right }_n $ converges in $W^{k,p}(U)$. Another fact is that if $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e. and $f_n$ converges to $g$ in ${W^{k,p}(U)}$, then $f=g$ a.e. . Therefore, we are done.

Why is $\sum_{i=1}^n \zeta_i u$ Cauchy? Imho it is not possible to prove convergence of this series.

@daw Because $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left | u^i-\zeta_i u \right | < \infty$, $\left { \sum_{i=0}^n \left | u^i-\zeta_i u \right |  \right }n$ is Cauchy. By triangle inequality, $\left | \sum{i=n}^m u^i-\zeta_i u \right | \le \sum_{i=n}^m \left | u^i-\zeta_i u \right |<\epsilon $. Is it alright?
